# Android BroadcaseReceiver performance (too slow & not accurate)

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, action

I made broadcasereceiver with 4 intent filter

- Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
- Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON
- Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT
- Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED

It works!!!
Every time I received broadcast message with 4 statement,
I can find Log message that works!!!

```
        @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.

        switch (intent.getAction()) {
            case Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON:
                Log.d("mypackage", "ACTION_SCREEN_ON");
                break;
            case Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF:
                Log.d("mypackage", "ACTION_SCREEN_OFF");
                break;
            case Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED:
                Log.d("mypackage", "ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED");
                break;
            case Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT:
                Log.d("mypackage", "ACTION_USER_PRESENT");
                break;
        }

    }
```

But problem is... it works but not well...
sometimes, after user actions, there's few seconds delay to read message..
and sometimes, log message doesn't even appear...

is it related with my code implementation? or just android poor performance??
plz help me~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the state of the app during the broadcast execution and the Android OS version where your application is executed.

Remember that a `BroadcastReceiver` is executed in the UI thread. If your application is performing any heavy task at the same time you try to process your event in the receiver this will be slow to process. You will see how the event does not arrive at your receiver until the UI thread looper is idle or how your UI has frozen until your receiver process the event.

I'd recommend you to review if at the same time you throw the event to your receiver your application is executing something in the UI thread.

To monitor my application in different devices and Android OS versions I use a tool I'm developing http://flowup.io using this tool I can control the frame rate I have in my app. Ideally, we should have 60 fps but that's not always possible :). Here you have an example of my application performance based on different devices and different Android OS versions:

[image]

As you can see, at some point the fps are quite low. That's because I had a bug in a service sorting a list of 1000 elements in the UI thread xD.

I'd recommend you to monitor your app and check if your problem is directly related to the receiver or the rest of the app executing code in the UI thread when this should be out of the UI thread. As this tool is still under development you can use other tools already released: traeview, systrace or the Android Studio performance monitor. You can subscribe to the mail list to know when the first release be published if you want.

If you still have to send an event you can use other alternatives as otto or busevent to replace the broadcast usage. This libraries can be used if the event you send does not depend on the application lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly it's the system. Saw various receive times for the same intent on different devices. It's annoying but there is not much you can do about it.

> "Even in the case of normal broadcasts, the system may in some
>   situations revert to delivering the broadcast one receiver at a time.
>   In particular, for receivers that may require the creation of a
>   process, only one will be run at a time to avoid overloading the
>   system with new processes. In this situation, however, the non-ordered
>   semantics hold: these receivers still cannot return results or abort
>   their broadcast."

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14043456)

Comment: Updated the response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to get it accurate

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        Log.e("In on receive", "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_OFF");
        countPowerOff++;

    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        Log.e("In on receive", "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_ON");
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
        Log.e("In on receive", "In Method:  ACTION_USER_PRESENT");
        if (countPowerOff > 2) {
            countPowerOff = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions?